# Which is the fastest way of extracting big table from db2 into sql

Tags: sql, performance, db2, extract

Can anyone suggest which is the fastest way of extracting a big table from db2 and load the data from it into sql db?
I don't want to group because I need this level of granularity.
Right now I am using an openquery.

Comment: What to you mean by big data?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have in db2 a table wich contains + 20 million rows. I need to do this just one time and I am connected to my db2 via linkedservers.

Comment: That is not "big data". That is just a lot of data in a table. The term "Big Data" is something completely different.

Comment: I agree, sorry for the terminology.

Comment: And what do you mean by "SQL"? SQL is the language that you use to manipulate a DB2 database. You don't extract **to SQL**. That's almost like asking "How do you translate a book written in English to language?"

Comment: I Extracted from DB2, I Transform the data and I Load it in SQL db... ETL. The question was , skipping the transformation step, wich is the fastest way to extract from db2 and load into sql db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to extract data in DB2 is export. This will generate comma separated values (cvs) files.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command- db2 "export to home/temp/text.csv of del modified by coldel, select * from table" from unix box when dealing with millions of rows. it will export results to text.csv file and you can modify path and your sql accordingly. CSV file can handle to save millions of rows but xls (excel sheet) will not be a good idea when we dealing with millions of row. once you have csv file you can use it for anywhere you need in the further process to load in to sql db as what you said.

Note: Prior to use the above command you need to connect to database from unix box using - db2 "connect to " command and when you finish with your sql execution you can close the connection using db2 "terminate". And why i suggest executing from unix command line because when you use TOAD for db2 or other tool it will crash when you are fetching millions of rows from tables and give your out of memory exceptions error.

Comment: more fits with comment